# multiple network interfaces, browser issue

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I have two network interfaces on my laptop: wireless, and wired. The wireless network is connected to the internet (automatic, dynamic ip assignment). The ethernet card is connected to an embedded system using static ip assignment (no internet there).

As long as I don't connect the ethernet cable, I can connect to the internet without any problems. After connecting the cable, I can communicate with my embedded system and all my network related apps (skype, dropbox, etc) work fine. However, my browser is no longer able to access the internet. Not even after I disconnect the ethernet cable.

I am using Windows 8.1 with Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Have you removed the default gateway from your inside dedicated card?
Set the internet gateway card as your preferred network device in the Networking Adapters properties

Are you comfortable setting Metric costs in an adapters properties

Replicated the problem with the included MS Internet Explorer determining if your problem is isolated to Chrome or the entire instnace of 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

When you connect your wired card, your default gateway (*i.e.*, the gateway through which all WAN communication is routed) changes to a gateway on the wired network. But since, as you stated, this cable only goes to an embedded system without direct access to the Internet, all Internet-using apps (browsers, torrent, putty, what not) are routed through a gateway without an exit onto the Internet.

All you have to do is to reconnect the wifi (which will restore the correct default gateway), or you can do it by hand.

When you do not have the cable connected, check you route by means of

```
  route print
```

the output, among many other things, will tell you the gateway you are using (let us say it is 192.168.1.1). Then, after connecting the cable, issue the command

```
  route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1
```

and now you should have both the local connection and the Internet connection.